# angular 8 y Chart.js Error: "getColors - Unsupported chart type undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, chart.js, angular7

Buen dia. Actualmente estoy intentando utilizar chart.js en angular 8. realice la instalacion utilizando los comandos:

```
npm install ng2-charts
npm install chart.js
```

Luego realice la importacion del modulo

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
```

y agregue a los import:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
RouterModule,
ChartsModule
```

],

con este codigo lo utilizo en bar-chart.component.html:

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

y en el codigo bar-chart.component.ts

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar el servidor tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo utilizando angular y chart.js asi que no doy con el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate que el error esta haciendo referencia a esta funcion propia de los charts:

```
function getColors(chartType, index, count) {
    if (chartType === 'pie' || chartType === 'doughnut') {
        return formatPieColors(generateColors(count));
    }
    if (chartType === 'polarArea') {
        return formatPolarAreaColors(generateColors(count));
    }
    if (chartType === 'line' || chartType === 'radar') {
        return formatLineColor(generateColor(index));
    }
    if (chartType === 'bar' || chartType === 'horizontalBar') {
        return formatBarColor(generateColor(index));
    }
    if (chartType === 'bubble') {
        return formatPieColors(generateColors(count));
    }
    if (chartType === 'scatter') {
        return formatPieColors(generateColors(count));
    }
    throw new Error(`getColors - Unsupported chart type ${chartType}`);
}
```

A mi me paso y era que tenia mal escrito el type. Fijate de pasarle en el chartType del html directamente el bar para ver si te lo toma mejor.

Saludos!!